# First pair out of order

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to know how to efficiently determine the first pair of elements in a list that are not in order according to some predicate p.  That is, list[i] > list[j] according to p, and i is the smallest index for which this is true. It is easy, but gauche, using nested loops.

Comment: Do you want the position as well?  The Accepted answer does not provide this.  Was *i* only for notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this test list

```
list = {1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6}
```

we can extract the first pair of elements that are not increasing as follows:

```
Select[Partition[list, 2, 1], ! Less @@ # &, 1]
```

> ```
> {{4,3}}
> ```

For other predicates you can adjust the second argument of [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) accordingly.

Comment: In V10 there is also `SelectFirst[Partition[list, 2, 1], Not@*OrderedQ]`

Comment: @Pickett Those composition shorthands are quite nice; I should upgrade at some point :).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this use of Partition.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern-matching approach:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6} /. {a___, x_, y_, b___} /; x > y :> {Length[{a}] + 1, {x, y}}
(* {4, {4, 3}} *)
```

That means `4>3` at the `4th` position in the list.

---

Another less elegant approach:

```
greaterQ = (Last@Take[list, #] > First@Drop[list, #] & /@ Range[Length@list - 1])~Append~False
(* {False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False} *)

p = Position[greaterQ, True]
(* {{4}} *)

list[[Flatten@{p, p + 1}]]
(* {4, 3} *)
```

Comment: I minor detail: you don't need `b` in `b___`.  By the way I like this answer best. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In **V10** There's `FirstCase`:

```
FirstCase[Partition[list, 2, 1], {x_, y_} /; x > y]
```

Otherwise:

```
Cases[Partition[list, 2, 1], {x_, y_} /; x > y, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

A method using `LengthWhile`:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6}

x = First @ list;
p = Less;
1 + LengthWhile[Rest @ list, p[x, x = #] &]
{list[[%]], x}
```

> ```
> 4
>
> {4, 3}
> ```

This gives the index and then the pair itself.   As a function:

```
f[l : {a_, b__}, p_] :=
 Module[{x = a},
   1 + LengthWhile[{b}, p[x, x = #] &] //
     {#, {l[[#]], x}} &
 ]

f[{9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4}, Greater]
```

> ```
> {4, {6, 7}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3};

sl = Split[list, Greater];
Select[sl, Length[#] >= 2 &, 1][[1, ;; 2]]
Cases[sl, {x_, y_, ___} :> {x, y}, 1, 1][[1]]
Pick[sl, Length[#] >= 2 & /@ sl][[1, ;; 2]]
sl[[LengthWhile[sl, Length[#] == 1 &] + 1, ;; 2]]
sl[[LengthWhile[sl, OrderedQ] + 1, ;; 2]]
Extract[Split[list, Less], {{1, -1}, {2, 1}}]
```

all give

```
(* {4, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

New in V10.1, [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html).

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6}
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} /; a > b, 1]
```

> `{{4, 3}}`